# OWASP ESAPI encodeForHTML with some allowed formatting tags

Tags: php, html, security, owasp, esapi

In a web project, we use OWASP ESAPI in PHP for output encoding. At some points, we'd like to allow a subset of HTML for little formatting options (for example, `<i>` and `<b>`), while disallowing all other tags and special characters (so they are entity-encoded using the `&...;` syntax).

I see the following possibilities to achieve this:

1. Tell [the OWASP ESAPI encoder](https://owasp-esapi-php.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/ESAPI/Encoder.html#methodencodeForHTML) to white-list / allow these tags so that it only encodes all other HTML tags and entities properly. But this doesn't seem to be supported. We could however (maybe) write a patch which allows this.
2. Decode the white-listed tags after encoding with ESAPI. Can this be attacked?
3. Use some other output encoding technique for this use case. Are there other libraries?

In particular, I need the following tags and attributes to be white-listed:

- `<br>`
- `<i>`
- `<b>`
- `<u>`
- `<big>`
- `<small>`
- `<sub>`
- `<sup>`
- `<font color="...">`
- `<ul>` + `<li>`
- `<ol>` + `<li>`

Please note that our application is security critical. This means that any method we are going to implement should only accept the tags above (and maybe some more formatting-only tags), everything else has to be entity-encoded properly. That this is true should be easily verifiable without doubt by looking at the (simple) code / explanation of the code. The shorter the code, the easier the reviews are. Fully hand-crafted encoders aren't good for this.

Comment: I clicked through the link and saw that the `encodeForHtml` method has no obvious "input encoding" parameter. That's kind of strange, but maybe it only accepts UTF-8? That would be a reasonable explanation. I went to find a download link to verify, and saw that [it says](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI#PHP) **not suitable for production use**. Strike one.

Comment: After hunting down the source I saw that the encoding is not specified because... [it is autodetected](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/source/browse/trunk/src/codecs/Codec.php#417). Strike two and there really is no need for a strike three. **I would not be caught dead using this code in a security critical application**, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Our security expert suggested us to use OWASP ESAPI... -.- In our current dev branch we use [htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php) anyway. But this might be even worse (at least we thought so, so it's currently only temporarily there).

Comment: Prefer `htmlspecialchars` to `htmlentities`, for the same reason as you should generally prefer ESAPI `encodeForXML` to `encodeForHTML`. The latter calls try to use HTML named entity references for a selection of Unicode characters, which is pointless and breaks when the encoding isn't right. Leaving the non-ASCII characters alone means you don't have to worry so much about charset at this level, and don't have to do anything stupid with the horrible autodetection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you are actually looking for is HTMLPurifier

http://htmlpurifier.org/

FWIW I am not affiliated with HTMLPurifier at all, and I am the Project Leader of the OWASP ESAPI project.

Answer (score 0):

In several of the projects I've worked on in the past I used the Codeigniter Security Class as a guideline to implement my own security functions.

Check out the source on GitHub here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php

There are several parts in this code related to encoding and xss. Might be useful for your situation.

Comment: CodeIgniter's approach to security, with blacklisting and cargo-cult input “sanitisation” is incredibly misguided and fragile.

Answer (score -1):

Check out code below, tested on PHP 5.3, works fine. Code comments added.

```
<?php

// test input data
$data = 'br1<br>,br3<br >,      br4<br/>,br2<br />, <i>i1</i><b>b1</b> foo<b onmouseover="alert(hi);">b1</b><u tricky="hello">u1</u> <big>big1</big><small>small1</small> <sub>sub1</sub><div name="aaaa">div1</div> <sup>sup1</sup><font>font1</font> <font       >font2</font><font onmouseover="alert(\'hi\');"  color="red" style="background-color:green;">font3</font><font onmouseover="alert(\'hi\');"  color="red" style="background-color:green;" >font4</font><ul><li>li1</li></ul><ol><li>li2</li></ol>';

// set the allowed tags and their allowed attribs
// case-insensitive
$allowed = array(
"br" => "", // second value is allowed attrs, "" means all attrs allowed for this tag
"i" => "",
"b" => "",
"u" => "",
"big" => "",
"small" => "",
"sub" => "",
"sup" => "",
"font" => "color,style", // comma separated list of allowed attrs, other attrs will be stripped out
"ul" => "",
"ol" => "",
"li" => "",
);

// this will contain output results
$outdata='';
// this func will do the job
fixit();
// print out the results
echo $outdata;

function start_element_handler($parser, $name, $attrs) {
    global $outdata,$allowed;
    // tag allowed, check further
    if( in_array($name,array_keys($allowed)) ) {
        $attrout="";
        if(!empty($attrs)) {
            foreach($attrs as $attr=>$val) {
                // attr allowed, write normal output, else skip the attr/val
                if(empty($allowed[$name]) || in_array($attr,$allowed[$name]))
                    $attrout=$attrout." ".strtolower($attr)."=\"$val\" ";
            }
        }
        $outdata=$outdata."<".strtolower($name)."$attrout>";
    }
    // tag not allowed, htmlentityencode the output
    else {
        $attrout="";
        if(!empty($attrs)) {
            foreach($attrs as $attr=>$val) {
                $attrout=$attrout." ".strtolower($attr)."=\"$val\" ";
            }
        }
        $outdata=$outdata.htmlentities("<".strtolower($name)."$attrout>",ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');
    }
}

function end_element_handler($parser, $name) {
    global $outdata,$allowed;
    // void elements have no ending tags, so skip writing to output
    $voids = array("AREA", "BASE", "BR", "COL", "COMMAND", "EMBED", "HR", "IMG", "INPUT", "KEYGEN", "LINK", "META", "PARAM", "SOURCE", "TRACK", "WBR");
    if(in_array($name,$voids))
        return;
    $nameout = "</".strtolower($name).">";
    // tag allowed, write normal output
    if( in_array($name,array_keys($allowed)) ) {
        $outdata=$outdata.$nameout;
    }
    // tag not allowed, htmlentityencode the output 
    else {
        $outdata=$outdata.htmlentities($nameout,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');
    }
}

function default_handler($parser, $data) {
    global $outdata,$allowed; $outdata=$outdata.htmlentities($data,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');
}

function fixit() {
    global $data, $allowed, $outdata;
    $outdata="";
    // added temp body tags to make xml parser work fine  
    $data="<body>{$data}</body>";
    // change allowed tags and attrs to uppercase for comparisons later
    $allowed=array_change_key_case($allowed,CASE_UPPER);
    foreach($allowed as $tag=>$attrs) $allowed[$tag] = array_filter(explode(",",strtoupper($attrs)));
    // create the parser
    $parser = xml_parser_create('UTF-8');
    // set to uppercase comparisons
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, true);
    xml_set_element_handler($parser, 'start_element_handler', 'end_element_handler');
    xml_set_default_handler($parser, 'default_handler');
    // parse the data 
    xml_parse($parser, $data, true);
    xml_parser_free($parser);
    // set output in $outdata variable
    $outdata = str_ireplace(array('&lt;body&gt;','&lt;/body&gt;'), "", $outdata); 
}

?>
```

Comment: The problem with this function is that it also allows any attribute on the allowed tags, such as in this example: `foo<b onmouseover="bad_attack()">bar</b>`

Comment: so, you want to allow specific tags and specific attrs within that too ?

Comment: how the input data is being created ? is it coming from user input ? tinymce ?

Comment: I want a specific subset of HTML, and for these tags only a specific subset of allowed attributes, namely those who only affect formatting (style, font, size, etc.) The input comes from [Qt rich text input, which allows a subset of HTML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html). But we can restrict the allowed set of tags to the one posted in the question. The attributes however aren't filtered by using `strip_tags`, which makes it possible to inject some `on...="..."` scripts.

Comment: Not HTML-encoding `$val` introduces new vulnerabilities, fail.